# Cannot call method 'substring' of undefined

Tags: extjs, tabs, portal, extjs4

Here is my code:

```
Ext.define('Ext.app.Portal', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Viewport',

    uses: ['Ext.app.PortalPanel', 'Ext.app.PortalColumn', 'Ext.app.GridPortlet', 'Ext.app.ChartPortlet'],

    getTools: function () {
        return [{
            xtype: 'tool',
            type: 'gear',
            handler: function (e, target, panelHeader, tool) {
                var portlet = panelHeader.ownerCt;
                portlet.setLoading('Working...');
                Ext.defer(function () {
                    portlet.setLoading(false);
                }, 2000);
            }
        }];
    },

    initComponent: function () {
        var content = '<div class="portlet-content">' + Ext.example.shortBogusMarkup + '</div>';

        Ext.apply(this, {
            id: 'app-viewport',
            layout: {
                type: 'border',
                padding: '0 5 5 5'
            }, //eo layout
            items: [{ //app-header : item 1 of app-viewport
                id: 'app-header',
                xtype: 'box',
                region: 'north',
                height: 40,
                html: 'My Portal'
            }, { //container : item 2 of app-viewport
                xtype: 'container',
                region: 'center',
                layout: 'border',
                items: [{ //app-options: item 1 of container
                    id: 'app-options',
                    title: 'Options',
                    region: 'west',
                    animCollapse: true,
                    width: 200,
                    minWidth: 150,
                    maxWidth: 400,
                    split: true,
                    collapsible: true,
                    layout: 'accordion',
                    layoutConfig: {
                        animate: true
                    },
                    items: [{ //portal: item 1 of app-options

                        title: 'portal',
                        autoScroll: true,
                        border: false,
                        iconCls: 'nav'
                    }, { //settings : item 2 of app-options
                        title: 'Settings',
                        html: '<div class="portlet-content">' + 'details ??' + '</div>',
                        border: false,
                        autoScroll: true,
                        iconCls: 'settings'
                    }] //eo items app-options
                }, { //item 2 of container    
                    id: 'app-portal',
                    xtype: 'tabpanel',
                    activeTab: 0,
                    region: 'center',
                    items: [{
                        title: 'tab1',
                        layout: 'column',
                        html: 'this is the first tab',
                        closable: true
                    }, {
                        title: 'tab2',
                        closable: true
                    } //eo tab2
                    ] //eo items tabpanel

                }]
            }] //eo   app-portal
        }); //eo apply

        this.callParent(arguments);
    },

    onPortletClose: function (portlet) {
        this.showMsg('"' + portlet.title + '" was removed');
    },

    showMsg: function (msg) {
        var el = Ext.get('app-msg'),
            msgId = Ext.id();

        this.msgId = msgId;
        el.update(msg).show();

        Ext.defer(this.clearMsg, 3000, this, [msgId]);
    },

    clearMsg: function (msgId) {
        if (msgId === this.msgId) {
            Ext.get('app-msg').hide();
        }
    }

});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first... i tried to copypaste your code, and replace it into portal sample,...
i didn't get your error, there is no `substring` error, but i got error in `tabpanel` part.. i think, the error is because `uses` config (this because substrin, can be found in classes.js)..

in portal sample, they use `Ext.app.PortalPanel`, `Ext.app.PortalColumn`, `Ext.app.GridPortlet`,and `Ext.app.ChartPortlet`,
but in your script you don't use it.. just remove `uses` part,
you don't need that, you just need tabpanel

second, see `classes.js` file there is no tabpanel define...
if you want to manipulate the portal without boundaries..
use the `ext-all.js` instead of `ext-core`..

change this :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../builds/ext-core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../shared/examples.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="classes.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="portal.js"></script>
```

to this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../shared/examples.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="portal.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks a  lot, i do need uses , i just removed that part to make sure the error is not from it. i added bootstrap, now i have a new error : **"Resuming debugger: error during debugging loop: TypeError: firstViewRangeElement is null"**   but now i can see the portal (not white screen) but i cant see the tabs

Comment: this is weird: i get this errir in firefox, but in chrome, i dont get an error (except missing png) .  but i still dont see the tabs, i can see the html content i put in the first one,but not the tabs !!

Comment: try to inject in your firebug with create a window contain tab panel inside,... if you can,. than this confused me too...

Comment: didnt understand what u want me to do!!   
if we forget about firefox,since in chrome i have no errors,why the tabs arent showing??

Comment: i dont have anymore errors in firefox either now :) (dont know what i did though :p ) .  now if i can get any idea on how to show the tabs...

Answer (score 6):

For others who might see "Cannot call method 'substring' of undefined", when I see this it's usually because of a problem finding an alias.  Usually a bad xtype.  For instance, if I use `xtype: 'img'` instead of `xtype: 'image'`.  I debug this by looking in the stack trace for 'instantiateByAlias' and look at the arguments for that call.  One of them is a config with the problematic xtype in it.

Comment: Thanks - setting a breakpoint in `instantiateByAlias` saved me. It's a shame Ext doesn't throw a more descriptive error when the xtype is unknown.

Answer (score 0):

tats correct Usually a bad xtype. For instance, if I use xtype: 'img' instead of xtype: 'image'. will cause this.